Collect log in Playwright .NET
I'm developing an automation tool using Playwright and am exploring ways to collect logs from Playwright, similar to the 'sink' concept in Serilog.
Is this possible with Playwright?
When running an application with
$env:DEBUG="pw:API" `
dotnet run

I see many logs from the console, how to collect them to another place, for example file or stream, etc

